# Converting QGIS expression into Excel function

Tags: qgis, excel, expression

In QGIS I use this expression to build a `"ID"` from fields:

```py
rpad(concat("abt", coalesce("u_abt",'X'),"beeinh"),5,'0') || '-Z01'
```

I need to translate this expression into a Excel or Calc function. How can I perform it?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: since I have no Idea, how to use Excel/Calc Syntax, I was hoping, someone does...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103881/is-there-a-coalesce-like-function-in-excel

Comment: Did you try something like this `=WENN(LÄNGE(VERKETTEN("abt"; VERGLEICH(FALSCH; ISTLEER(A2:C2); FALSCH); "beeinh")) < 5; VERKETTEN("abt"; VERGLEICH(FALSCH; ISTLEER(A2:C2); FALSCH); "beeinh") & WIEDERHOLEN("*"; 5 - LÄNGE(VERKETTEN("abt"; VERGLEICH(FALSCH; ISTLEER(A2:C2); FALSCH); "beeinh"))); LINKS(VERKETTEN("abt"; VERGLEICH(FALSCH; ISTLEER(A2:C2); FALSCH); "beeinh"); 5))&"-Z01"`?

Comment: Or in English `=IF(LENGTH(CONCATENATE("abt"; MATCH(FALSE; ISBLANK(A2:C2); FALSE); "beeinh")) < 5; CONCATENATE("abt"; MATCH(FALSE; ISBLANK(A2:C2); FALSE); "beeinh") & WIEDERHOLEN("*"; 5 - LENGTH(CONCATENATE("abt"; MATCH(FALSE; ISBLANK(A2:C2); FALSE); "beeinh"))); LINKS(CONCATENATE("abt"; MATCH(FALSE; ISBLANK(A2:C2); FALSE); "beeinh"); 5))&"-Z01"`

Comment: I read about the new `LET` function (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) that is coming to excel and thought it would be cool to find a good case for its use. And then I find this question :) When the `LET` function is widely supported the above english version can be written `=LET(s; CONCATENATE("abt"; MATCH(FALSE; ISBLANK(A2:C2); FALSE); "beeinh"); IF(LENGTH(s) < 5; s & REPEAT("*"; 5 - LENGTH(s)); LEFT(s; 5))&"-Z01")`